# Print MS Access Report using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, printing, report

I research everywhere on how I can print an MS Access Report using VB.NET but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find one. Maybe there's anybody who can help me here with my problem. Anyone?

Comment: I don't think you can. But VB.NET can show Crystal Reports, which is very similar to Access Reports.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about VB.NET, but the following code uses VBA which is very similar.

Instead of opening the report using
`DoCmd.OpenReport "reportName", acViewPreview,,, acWindowNormal,`
(which opens it in Print Preview mode so that the user can select a printer and print it out themselves), use:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "reportName", acViewNormal,,, acWindowNormal,`

This will print the report using the default printer installed on the computer.

Alternatively, you can use the `DoCmd.PrintOut()` command (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192667.aspx)